# SharePoint 2003 Activity Reporting

Tags: sharepoint

We use SPS 2003 for our intranet. Is there a good tool for reporting on site activity from the IIS logs? I have tried WebTrends (old version) and Deep Log Analyzer. DLA uses MS Access so it can not hold all of the log data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Logparser is probably your best bet here - 
[download here](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en)

I used it to analyze our sharepoint traffic (who was reading what articles, etc.).

Here's some good blog postings that walk you through:

http://blogs.technet.com/corybu/archive/2008/02/26/sharepoint-iis-traffic-analysis.aspx

http://drtadd.blogspot.com/2005/03/logparser-rocks-what-are-users.html

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=85

hope this helps ...

Answer (score 1):

I know you specifically asked about IIS data - but have you looked at the [SharePoint Usage Analysis](http://office.microsoft.com/download/afile.aspx?AssetID=AM102437481033) reports?